# window history back (-1) not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have use below code to back for the previous page, but it's not working. the alert box still popup even i click ok on the page. 
actually there have 3 page include this windows page code. 1st page is user need to fill up the form is name redeem_newcust.asp and the action should be save all the data into the database named redeem_newcustDB.asp. In page redeem_newcustDB.asp have one code to select option for type of redemption then this page will point action to the page redeem_newprocess.asp with is included as below code. Means when user click on type of redemption not equal to "Birthday Pack - PDV RM50" then it should be back to the previous page that means page redeem_newcustDB.asp. 
It's possible to having back to that previous page..? Should b need to bring all the value?
Please help, thanks

```
If redeemtype = "Birthday Pack - PDV RM50" then
        Response.Redirect("redeem_newbirth.asp?cardno="&BlinkCard&"&redeemtype="&redeemtype&"")
    Else
        %>
            <script language="javascript">
            <!--
            window.alert ("Please choose Type of Redemption");
            window.history.go(-1);
            //-->
            </script>
        <%   
End If

%>
```

Comment: Sometimes `alert()` kills script in IE.

Comment: so, have another alternative for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use: `window.history.back()` instead `.go();`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

or use:

```
window.alert("Please choose Type of Redemption");
setTimeout(function(){
  window.history.go(-1);
},500);
```

Comment: +1 for setTimeout, but please do not reference w3fools, they're bad people.

Comment: i try but still not working, the popup alert box still appear even i click ok.. i need to close all the tab.

Answer (score 1):

I would always avoid using `alert()`, since it kills script in some Browsers. I would `open()` a new window and `ButtonElement.onclick` use `location =`.

Note:

`window` is implicit, so you don't need to write `window.open()` or `window.location`. Additionally, it's fine to leave off `.href` when referring to `location.href`