# Liferay back button issue

Tags: javascript, liferay

I am a beginner in Liferay, and I started with Liferay 7.0 for development, I have a issue with back button.

I have 3 jsp pages, from page 1 to page 2, then click back then it back to page 1, but from page 2 go to page 3, then click back at page 3 then it back to page 1 (correct is page 2).

I am using "onclick="javascript:window.history.back(-1);return false" on jsp page 3, I delve into it 1 day but still not work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It is either `history.back()` or `history.go(-1)` as mentioned in [window history back (-1) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694754/window-history-back-1-not-working)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, i will try to use them.

Comment: Thank for your help, but it is still not work as i want